# Game behaves differently on the actual device

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, sprite-kit

I am replicating the game flappy bird using the Apple SpriteKit. Everything's done and it works great when I do a test run through the Xcode simulator, but when I test it with my actual iPhone the bird does not go through the first pipe. It's like there is something blocking it from going through.

If I make the gap between the pipes wider the bird does go through. I found out that there is something invisible above and below the pipes (like the bird can sit 5px above the pipe so it could never actually touch the top of the pipe). Which is weird because it works fine on the simulator.

```
_upward_pipe.physicsBody = [SKPhysicsBody bodyWithRectangleOfSize:_upward_pipe.size];
_downward_pipe.physicsBody = [SKPhysicsBody bodyWithRectangleOfSize:_downward_pipe.size];
```

this is how the size of each pipe's physicbody is setup.

I tried adding just one non-moving pipe in the middle of the screen and if I do that the bird does touch the top of the pipe (no invisible pixels).

I am using iPhone 5 with iOS 7.0. I'm not sure how I should figure out what the problem is. Can anyone guide me please?

Comment: Is your frame-rate on the device the same as simulator? In my case frame-rate was much lower on simulator so physics were always calculated differently due to delta time.

Comment: Standard opening question: are you sure the difference is device versus simulator or is it possibly release build versus debug build? Have you just failed to initialise something, causing you to rely on undefined behaviour?

Comment: i think you need to upgrade your iOS 7.0 to 7.1 where you can see all physics bodies by allowing skView.showPhysics=yes may be that can help you